# Create Pandas Data Frames from Array

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

How do I create a new data frame named after each entry in an array?

I have an array created from a Pandas data frame column.  It looks something like below.

```
[In]  company_id = df.COMPANY_IDENTIFICATION.unique()
[In]  company_id
[OUT] array(['BBG000QFYJ26', 'BBG000C0ZQY2', 'BBG000LNZ408', ..., 'BBG000QXGV57',
   'BBG0022MJRB2', 'BBG0025394S5'], dtype=object)
```

I created a simple loop, but I don't think it's working correctly.

```
for i in company_id:
    i = pd.DataFrame()
```

As a test, I had it print i after each iteration.

```
for i in company_id:
    i = pd.DataFrame()
    print(i)
```

Output was:

> Index: []
>
> Empty DataFrame
>
> Columns: []
>
> Index: []
>
> Empty DataFrame
>
> Columns: []
>
> etc.

I also can't call the datframes by the names I know are in the array.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better idea is to store your dataframes in a dictionary, with names as keys:

```
d= {i: pd.DataFrame() for i in company_id}
```

Then you can refer to individual dataframes via dictionary keys, e.g. `d['BBG000QFYJ26']`.

You can iterate the dictionary via `dict.items()`:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    # perform operation
```